# How Do We Update Xcode for Changes to a Doppl Project?

Tags: doppl

Suppose we have an Android project with Doppl integrated. We set up the Xcode workspace via `pod install`, write some Swift, and everything is working fine.

Now, we add a method to a Java class that is part of the Doppl translation, such as a unit test class. We run `dopplBuild` (with Xcode closed for safety), reopen the Xcode workspace, and everything is working fine, including the new method.

However, when we try changing the mix of classes, that flow (`dopplBuild`, reopen Xcode) appears to be insufficient. For example, if we add another unit test class (including adding it to `dopplConfig`), our test runner can't find it. If we remove a class from `translatePattern` and `testIdentifier`, and are no longer referring to it from our code, the Xcode build fails because it thinks that class should still be there.

What should we be doing to get Xcode to know about these bigger changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `pod update`. While you do not appear to need this for the smaller changes (adding/removing methods, changing method implementations), you do need it when you wind up adding or removing classes from what you had previously.

Also note that `pod update` does not change anything else, such as any `dopplTests.txt` file that you may have copied into your workspace. You will need to update those separately yourself by hand.